How to control the ordering of menu items in a Traits/UI GUI application?
I'm adding a menu to my Enthought Traits/UI GUI application, like so:
# Main window layout definition.
traits_view = View(
    Group(
        {snip}
    ),
    menubar=MenuBar(
        Menu(
            Action(name="Load Config.", action="do_load_cfg", accelerator="Ctrl+O"),
            Action(name="Load Results", action="do_load_data"),
            Separator(),
            Action(name="Save Config.", action="do_save_cfg", accelerator="Ctrl+S"),
            Action(name="Save Config. As...", action="do_save_cfg_as", accelerator="Ctrl+Shift+S"),
            Action(name="Save Results", action="do_save_data"),
            Separator(),
            Action(name="&Quit", action="close_app", accelerator="Ctrl+Q"),  # CloseAction()
            id="file",
            name="&File",
        ),
        {snip}
    ),
)

But, I'm not getting the ordering of menu items correct (i.e. - as ordered in my code above) in the application GUI.
Instead, they're showing up in (almost) reverse alphabetical order:
Save Config.
Save Config. As...
Save Results
==================
Quit
==================
Load Config.
Load Results

How do I explicitly control the ordering of the menu items in my Traits/UI GUI application?
